# We know that D is a diagonal matrix and M has only ones in the entries. Can we say something about the eigenvalues of D+M?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Both matrices are trivial and it is easy to find their eigenvalues, but I can't find the eigenvalues of the sum D+M.

Comment: Is $D=cI$ by any chance? Either way you can bound the eigenvalues.

Comment: are the diagonals elements of D all the same constant?

Comment: Can you be more clear about this matrix $M$?  I don't understand exactly what you mean by "has only ones" do you mean every single entry in $M$ is a one?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I think they mean $M$ is a [matrix of ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones).

Comment: if you have a one matrix of size n by n, the eigenvalues are 0 with multiplicity n-1 and an eigenvalue n. As @par suggested, adding that to the knowledge of D, you can effectively bound the eigenvalues

Comment: In general, when you add matrices together nothing about their eigenvalues or eigenvectors is predictable.  I will give one exception.  If two matrices have the same eigenvector, then that vector will be an eigenvector of their sum, and the eigenvalue for that vector will be the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: The diagonal elements are not the same constant. Matrix M is [1]ij, matrix of ones.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ denote the vector containing only $1$s.  We note (by applying [the matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)) that
$$
\det(\lambda I - (D + M)) = 
\det((\lambda I - D) - vv^T) = (1 - v^T(\lambda I - D)^{-1}v) \det(\lambda I - D)
$$
So, if $\lambda$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $D$ (i.e. one of the values on the diagonal), then it is an eigenvalue of $D + M$ if and only if 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda - d_{ii}} = 1
$$

Comment: Perfect answer! You helped a lot! I didn't know this lemma. But I have a doubt: the sum equals -1, right?

Comment: Do you know how can I solve this equation?

Comment: There is no good general solution. Really, what I've given you is a nice way to find the characteristic polynomial, and you can't do much better without knowing more about $D$.

Answer (score 1):

If the diagonal elements of $D$ are $d_1,\ldots,d_n$, the eigenvalues of $M$ are $(n,0,0,\ldots)$ (it is a rank-$1$ matrix) and the eigenvalues of $D+M$ are bounded in absolute value by $n+\max_i |d_i|$. If $D=cI$, the eigenvalues of $D+M$ are exactly $(c+n,c,c,\ldots)$.